# How to deserialize fields into object using jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I tried deserialize following json to POJO.

```
{
  "foo": {
    "key1":"dummy",
    "key2":"dummy"
  },
  "bar": {
    "key1":"dummy",
    "key2":"dummy",
    "key3":"dummy"
  },
  "bazKey1":"dummy",
  "bazKey2":"dummy",
  "bazKey3":"dummy",
  "bazKey4":"dummy"

  // Many others....
}
```

You can see above strange `baz` properties...
But I want to treat `baz` as an object like `foo` and `bar`.

```
public class Pojo {
  private Foo foo;
  private Bar bar;
  private Baz baz;

  // Many others....
}
```

However, I just found poor solution which uses custom deserializer.

### Poor solution

```
@Override
public Pojo deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws Exception {
  ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
  JsonNode node = codec.readTree(p);

  Baz baz = new Baz.Builder()
      .key1(node.get("bazKey1").textValue())
      .key2(node.get("bazKey2").textValue())
      .key3(node.get("bazKey3").textValue())
      .key4(node.get("bazKey4").textValue())
      .build();

  // We have to write annoying (setter/constructor/builder) instead of below method.
  // return codec.treeToValue(node, Pojo.class);
  return new Pojo.Builder()
      .foo(foo)
      .bar(bar)
      .baz(baz)
      .other(other)
      .other(other)
      .other(other) // Many others...
      .build();
}
```

This solution forces us to use annoying (setter/constructor/builder).

---

How to deserialize fields into object using jackson?
Additionally, this POJO is **Immutable** object.

Comment: I think you're looking for references outlined [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation-Jackson-2.0) using the [JsonIdentityInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) annotation.

Comment: You could have a Baz class wrapping Foo and Bar

Comment: It looks like `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz` classes have the same properties. Does it true? "Many others ..." means that you have other `POJO`s which looks like `Foo`,`Bar`?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous. I updated my question. This is not about circular references. Also `Foo` and `Bar` are just sample.

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes I have 10+ `POJO` like `Foo` and `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The point of Jackson is that you're not in this situation. The very reason why you use Jackson at all is because when you have a Baz Java object, it's represented with a baz JSON property that contains an object, and when you have several string JSON properties, they are represented in Java with several String fields of the same name.

If that's not the situation you're in, then there is no reason to consider Jackson. Use any JSON parsing library, and build your Java objects from the JSON tree. You can use Java reflection to discover the Java class' fields/methods and set/call them based on the JSON properties' names.